# Using another browser than w3m for reading HTML helpfiles?

Tags: fish, w3m

I'm using fish as shell. The internal help is based on html files and when I type help it opens w3m to view this help files. Since w3m is not my default browser I wonder where this configuration to start w3m for this is stored. I'd like to read the helpfiles with another browser. How can I setup another one for this purpose or perhaps where are the helpfiles located so I can open them manually in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use, as an example, elinks to view the fish documentation, type

```
elinks /usr/share/doc/fish/index.html
```

You can also use `firefox` or `google-chrome` in the same way.

I found the location by looking at `type help`, which returned the function definition. In there, I found a reference to the variable `$__fish_help_dir`, which contains `/usr/share/doc/fish` (using `echo $__fish_help_dir`).

There's a [discussion on their mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/fish-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00562.html) on the subject as well.

Comment: thanks a lot. ok, then i guess, using w3m is fish specific in this case and it can't customized in the way that it automatically uses another browser when help is executed. is /usr/share/doc/ the preferred directory to find application documentation?

Comment: Yes it is. See the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) for more on that.